# Insertion of code blocks in sx.el

Tags: markdown, sx.el

In sx.el compose mode, what is the correct way to mark some region as
a code block, the way <kbd>C-k</kbd> does it on the web interface ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select a region and run the command `markdown-insert-pre` (`C-c C-s p` for me), it will mark the selected region as preformatted text. I am not sure if there is any difference, but for me it seems to indent the region as a code block. You can also start a code block this way if there is no active region.

Also, `C-c C-s c` will wrap selection in backticks or give you a pair of backticks with the cursor in the middle so you can write a code snippet

Comment: Thanks. I'd been looking through sx- commands instead of markdown-.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of hidden and the name does not make any reference to "code" or "block", so it is not clear by looking through command names. I actually stumbled upon it by looking through the menu for `sx-compose-mode`. I almost never use the menus, but this is one thing that they are handy for.